# Is it possible to set a default value on a property with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using Fluent NHibernate for my mappings and the SchemaExport class to the database schema.

Is it possible with NHibernate to set a default value for a property/column in the generated database schema?

Comment: The accepted answer is not (no longer?) correct. I've provided details in a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge, no - not in the generated schema.

You can just set the property in your constructor though.

Comment: I didn't think so. I'm resulting to just setting it in the constructor for now as you've said. It just means when updating an existing database schema from a newly exported schema from the mappings I have to go thru a manual process to add it.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely supported, both in XML mapping and in Fluent NHibernate.

- For XML mapping, use the `<column>` child element of `<property>`, [documented here](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-column).
- For Fluent NHibernate, there's a method for fluent mapping, as [described in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568843/639520).